# how to get to the next element of list inside for loop in django template?

Tags: python-3.x, django, list, django-templates

i have a list like

```
lst = [
       ['img1','img2','img3','img4','img5'], 
       ['img6','img7','img8','img9']
      ]
```

and a template like

```
<div class="row">                               -- 1st row
   <div class="col-lg-3" data-aos="fade-up">    --col-lg-3
      <a href="{{img1}}">  --img1
        <img src="{{img1}}">                    -- img1
      </a>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">    --col-lg-6
       <a href="{{img2}}">   --img2
          <img src="{{img2}}">                    --img2
       </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">    --col-lg-3
        <a href="{{img}}">   --img3
           <img src="{{img}}">                    --img3
       </a>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="row">                                 ---2nd row

   <div class="col-lg-8" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">    --col-lg-8
       <a href="{{img2}}">   --img2
          <img src="{{img2}}">                    --img2
       </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">    --col-lg-4
        <a href="{{img}}">   --img3
           <img src="{{img}}">                    --img3
       </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

please note few things:

1. every col-lg size is of different size
2. every  and  tag of a column contain 1 img

i want to iterate over the whole template but in a different way

eg: i can do this in python where i can iterator over list and assign the value as well

```
for data in lst:
  it = iter(data)

  print (next(it))    ---where print will be replaced with img tag 
  print (next(it))  
  print (next(it))
  print (next(it))
  print (next(it))
```

but how can i do this in django template

Answer (score 0):

Django's `for-in template` loop builds the DOM defined between the template tag loop for each item in data.

That being said, you could adapt your solution like so:

```
<div class="row align-items-stretch">
                     
{% for img in data %}
                     
   <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3" data-aos="fade-up">
      <a href="{{ data.img }}" class="d-block photo-item" data-fancybox="gallery">  
        <img src="{{ data.img.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">                    
        <div class="photo-text-more">
           <span class="icon icon-camera"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
   </div>
                     
{% endfor %}

</div>
```

If `data` contains three items/images, the output will be something like:

```
<div class="row align-items-stretch">
                     
   # 1st iteration   
               
   <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3" data-aos="fade-up">
      <a href="href_according_to_data" class="d-block photo-item" data-fancybox="gallery">  
        <img src="link" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">                    
        <div class="photo-text-more">
           <span class="icon icon-camera"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
   </div>


   # 2nd iteration

   <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3" data-aos="fade-up">
      <a href="href_according_to_data" class="d-block photo-item" data-fancybox="gallery">  
        <img src="link" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">                    
        <div class="photo-text-more">
           <span class="icon icon-camera"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
   </div>


   # 3rd iteration

   <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3" data-aos="fade-up">
      <a href="href_according_to_data" class="d-block photo-item" data-fancybox="gallery">  
        <img src="link" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">                    
        <div class="photo-text-more">
           <span class="icon icon-camera"></span>
        </div>
      </a>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanx. but this is not what i want . i think i had not explain it well. i will try it again.